# Raspberry Pi rc.local

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi

I have a raspberry pi, and am settings it up to run TwoToneDetect. I have a .py file that boots it, and I can run it from the command line via `/home/pi/TTD/boot.sh`, but when I add that to the rc.local, nothing happens

Comment: I suspect that you will need to provide more detail, for this to be answered. Please **edit question** to tell us what worker. And what did not. Be precise. e.g How did you add it? What is in the script?

Answer (score 0):

Take all the commands you have at `/home/pi/TTD/boot.sh` and put them in `rc.local`
In `rc.local`. Use the correct absolute full paths to your commands, `&` at the end of your command. There should already be an `#!/bin/sh -e` or similar shebang at the beginning of the file and `exit 0` at the end. Leave them intact and put your commands in between.

```
/bin/TwoToneDetect &
...
exit 0
```

That's said. The recommendation nowadays is to use systemd instead and I quote from https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/rc-local.md

> NOTE: on Jessie, Stretch and Buster (which use `systemd`), `rc.local` has drawbacks: not all programs will run reliably, because not all services may be available when `rc.local` runs.
>   See `systemd` for another way to have a command or program run when Raspberry Pi boots.

Comment: Be sure to add your shebang at the beginning of rc.local too, or it may fail to run, which I suspect is happening.